# Centos 6 startup script

Tags: linux, centos, startup, centos6

I need to put a startup script to my CentOS6 server.

I see that I need a script that contains start-stop cases.
But I have a problem to make it and neither how to put this script to startup.

Anyone can say me how can I add it?

The script must run a simply command that run a jar file:

```
java -jar FileName.jar
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add your command to the file

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Commands in the above file are run at startup (as root).  Note that if you do this, your command will NOT respond to the usual service start/ stop commands.

Comment: Perfect! this is what i need.
But i have a question.
The script is blocking (if i start it from console, this will be blocked until the END of the program, never)
I must put a command with nohup? like:
`nohup java -jar FileName.jar &`

Comment: @Univers3 - hmmm... I've never really used `nohup` so I can't comment on it. But if it is blocking, I would definitely try the `&` at the end.

Comment: How do you stop a command run like this? It doesn't seem to show up when running 'ps'

Comment: @BT did you try `ps -A` ?

Comment: i did now, tho it can be a little hard to figure out which process it is. Thanks!

Comment: I have program called 'icecast' and i have green file executable i guess, how do i add it to services to start with system without this old-fashion method you mentioned?